# Using regex to remove substrings from list items in python

Tags: python, regex, list

Im sure this must be a duplicate question but I can't find an answer anywhere. I have a list with multiple strings as below:

```
['>ctg7180000016561_3757\nAAAAATTTAGTTAAAACTATAACATTAGCTTGTCAAGCTAAAATTACTATGTAAGTAGTAATTTTTA\n', '>ctg7180000016561_3824\nATCCCTCAAATAGCACCCATTAACTGATTATCCTTATTCTTAATATTCACCACCTCTCTCCTAATATTTAGAGCTTCTAACTATTTCTTTATCATGTACCCCCCCAAAAAATCTGTTTTTTATAAAAAAACTAGTATAAATAACTGATCATGATAACTAACCTCTTTTCGTCTTTCGACCCCTCTACTAACTTAAATACTAACTTTAACTGAGTTAGGACTATCCTCGGGGTGGCTGTAATCCCGAGGATATTTTGGATTATCCCCTCGCGTTTCTCCCTGCTTTGAATAAAACTTATCAGTACTCTTCACAAAGAATTCAAAGTCCTTGTTAACAACAAAAAATCCCAAGGCAGAACCCTAATCCTGATTTCCTTATTTTCTATTATTTTATTTAATAACTTCATAGGACTATTCCCATATATTTTCACATCCACAAGTCACATAGTATTAACCCTGTCCCTGGCTCTCCCCATATGACTAAGATTTATATTGTATGGGTGGGTAAATAATACAACCCACATGCTAGCCCATCTAGTACCCCAAGGAACCCCTGCCGTTCTAATACCATTTATGGTGTGTATTGAAACAATCAGAAATGTTATCCGACCCGGCACCCTGGCAATCCGGCTATCCGCAAATATAATTGCAGGACACCTACTAATAACCCTTCTAGGTAACACGGGAAAC\n', '>ctg7180000016561_4513\nT\n']
```

And all I want to do is remove the numbers after the underscore, so in this example the output would be:

```
['>ctg7180000016561\nAAAAATTTAGTTAAAACTATAACATTAGCTTGTCAAGCTAAAATTACTATGTAAGTAGTAATTTTTA\n', '>ctg7180000016561\nATCCCTCAAATAGCACCCATTAACTGATTATCCTTATTCTTAATATTCACCACCTCTCTCCTAATATTTAGAGCTTCTAACTATTTCTTTATCATGTACCCCCCCAAAAAATCTGTTTTTTATAAAAAAACTAGTATAAATAACTGATCATGATAACTAACCTCTTTTCGTCTTTCGACCCCTCTACTAACTTAAATACTAACTTTAACTGAGTTAGGACTATCCTCGGGGTGGCTGTAATCCCGAGGATATTTTGGATTATCCCCTCGCGTTTCTCCCTGCTTTGAATAAAACTTATCAGTACTCTTCACAAAGAATTCAAAGTCCTTGTTAACAACAAAAAATCCCAAGGCAGAACCCTAATCCTGATTTCCTTATTTTCTATTATTTTATTTAATAACTTCATAGGACTATTCCCATATATTTTCACATCCACAAGTCACATAGTATTAACCCTGTCCCTGGCTCTCCCCATATGACTAAGATTTATATTGTATGGGTGGGTAAATAATACAACCCACATGCTAGCCCATCTAGTACCCCAAGGAACCCCTGCCGTTCTAATACCATTTATGGTGTGTATTGAAACAATCAGAAATGTTATCCGACCCGGCACCCTGGCAATCCGGCTATCCGCAAATATAATTGCAGGACACCTACTAATAACCCTTCTAGGTAACACGGGAAAC\n', '>ctg7180000016561\nT\n']
```

I am using regex and I have a perfect match but I cant work out how to actually remove the substrings. My code so far is:

```
pattern = re.compile('_[0-9]*')
for x in SequenceList:
    re.sub(pattern, '', x)
```

I'm aware that this is just changing the variable x, but even when I just `print x` within the for loop the pattern isn't removed. How do I actually remove the pattern and alter the list?

Thank you and sorry if this is already answered somewhere!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings are immutable. So, `re.sub` will create a new string. Instead, you can use list comprehension to create a new list with the replaced strings like this

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"_\d+")
print [pattern.sub("", item) for item in data]
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thankyou. Out of interest is there a reason you chose the pattern _\d+ over _[0-9]*?

Comment: @PaulBarr `\d` is easy to write :-) Apart from that, `_[0-9]*` will replace the `_` even if there are no numbers following that, because `*` means to match 0 or more times. So, if the string is `_a`, it will match `_` and match the number 0 times.